# Python - key error when using "if in dict"

Tags: python, xml, dictionary, key, iteration

I am receiving the following error when running a script to parse contents of an XML file.

```
if iteration.findtext("Iteration_query-def") in ecdict:
KeyError: 'XLOC_000434'
```

I was under the impression that using "if in dict" would mean that if the key is not found in the dictionary, the script will continue past the if statement and proceed with the rest of the code. Below is the problematic section of the code I am using. I realise this is quite a basic question, but I am unsure what else I can say, and I don't understand why I am receiving this error.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('507.FINAL_14.2.14_2_nr.out_fmt5.out')
blast_iteration = tree.find("BlastOutput_iterations")
for iteration in blast_iteration.findall("Iteration"):
        query = iteration.findtext("Iteration_query-def").strip().strip("\n")
        if query in score:
                continue
        if iteration.findtext("Iteration_message") == "No hits found":
                if iteration.findtext("Iteration_query-def") in tair:
                        tairid = tair[iteration.findtext("Iteration_query-def")][0]
                        tairdes = tair[iteration.findtext("Iteration_query-def")][1]
                else:
                                        tairid = "-"
                                        tairdes = "-"
                goterms = ""
                ecterms = ""
                if iteration.findtext("Iteration_query-def") in godict:
                                        for x in godict[iteration.findtext("Iteration_query-def")][:-1]:
                                                goterms = goterms + x + ";"
                                        goterms = goterms + godict[iteration.findtext("Iteration_query-def")][-1]
                else:
                                        goterms = "-"
                if iteration.findtext("Iteration_query-def") in ecdict:
                                        for x in ecdict[iteration.findtext("Iteration_query-def")][:-1]:
                                                ecterms = ecterms + x + ";"
                                        ecterms = ecterms + ecdict[iteration.findtext("Iteration_query-def")][-1]
                else:
                                        ecterms = "-"
                if iteration.findtext("Iteration_query-def") in godescr:
                        desc = godescr[iteration.findtext("Iteration_query-def")]
                else:
                        desc = "-"
                n += 1
                p = "PvOAK_up"+str(n) + "\t" + tranlen[iteration.findtext("Iteration_query-def")] + "\t" + orflen[iteration.findtext("Iteration_query-def")] + "\t" + "-" + "\t" + "-" + "\t" + tairid  + "\t" + tairdes + "\t" + goterms + "\t" + ecterms + "\t" + desc + "\t" + str(flower[query][2]) + "\t" + str('{0:.2e}'.format(float(flower[query][1]))) + "\t" + str('{0:.2f}'.format(float(flower[query][0]))) + "\t" + str('{0:.2f}'.format(float(leaf[query][2]))) + "\t" + str('{0:.2f}'.format(float(leaf[query][1]))) + "\t" + str('{0:.2f}'.format(float(leaf[query][0])))
                print p
```

Hope you can help,

Thanks.

edit: I should say that godict and ecdict were previously created as follows - I can submit the entire code if needs be:

```
godict = {}
ecdict = {}
godescr = {}
f = open("507.FINAL_14.2.14_2_nr.out_fmt5.out.annot")
for line in f:
        line = line.split("\t")
        if len(line) > 2:
                godescr[line[0]] = line[2]
        line[1] = line[1].strip("\n")
        if line[1].startswith("EC"):
                if line[0] in ecdict:
                        a = ecdict[line[0]]
                        a.append(line[1])
                        ecdict[line[0]] = a
                else:
                        ecdict[line[0]] = [line[1]]
        else:
                if line[0] in godict:
                        a = godict[line[0]]
                        a.append(line[1])
                        godict[line[0]] = a
                else:
                        godict[line[0]] = [line[1]]
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2d.test.py", line 170, in <module>
    p = "PvOAK_up"+str(n) + "\t" + tranlen[iteration.findtext("Iteration_query-def")] + "\t" + orflen[iteration.findtext("Iteration_query-def")] + "\t" + "-" + "\t" + "-" + "\t" + tairid  + "\t" + tairdes + "\t" + goterms + "\t" + ecterms + "\t" + desc + "\t" + str(flower[query][2]) + "\t" + str('{0:.2e}'.format(float(flower[query][1]))) + "\t" + str('{0:.2f}'.format(float(flower[query][0]))) + "\t" + str('{0:.2f}'.format(float(leaf[query][2]))) + "\t" + str('{0:.2f}'.format(float(leaf[query][1]))) + "\t" + str('{0:.2f}'.format(float(leaf[query][0])))
KeyError: 'XLOC_000434'
```

Comment: Could `iteration.findtext("Iteration_query-def")` be the exception source?

Comment: `<something> in <standard dictionary>` **won't ever** throw a `KeyError`; what is the **complete** traceback? Are you sure you restarted Python with the latest revision of your code?

Comment: @user2864740 "Iteration_query-def" refers to the tag of that name in the XML file being parsed - this part seems fine.

Comment: @MartijnPieters There does not appear to be any more information in the log (I submitted through LSF on a unix cluster). I will create a smaller example file and rerun.

Comment: have you tried using ecdict.get(.. etc..  instead of ecdict[..

Comment: Adding more code is the wrong direction -- trying to reproduce the problem with *less* code would be helpful. See http://sscce.org/

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have added the traceback as requested. I hope it is complete, but it does not seem to show much additional detail in this case.

Comment: ...the very fact that the traceback doesn't show more detail is itself very helpful. It tells us that the problem isn't inside the findtext() call, but is more likely the result of findtext() not being present in tranlen. Notably, this **isn't** a "if in dict" usage, making this question's subject misleading.

Comment: @user1966712: it does; it tells up your initial error report was incorrect. The `KeyError` is thrown by one of the *many* item accesses on that line (any of the expressions using `[...]`).

Comment: @user1966712: it appears you want to create a tab-separated file. Perhaps you wanted to use the `csv` module instead.

Comment: I now realise my error, 000434 is not in orflen and I really should have known. The reason is that "tranlen" represents the length of each transcribed part of the genome sequence I am working with, which may or may not be a gene. "orflen" meanwhile is the length of the part of that sequence that is predicted to code for a gene, termed "open reading frame". 000434 is one such sequence that did not have a predicted orf, and is therefore not in the orflen dictionary. Thank you all for your help in finding the problem. I will explore the use of the csv module.